# Can commited login credentials on http be seen on firefox dev tool?

Tags: http, firefox, encryption, passwords, credentials

Heyllo,

I'm just looking around Firefox Dev Tool and I committed a username and a password over http to a web interface of my IP cam (Foscam IP Cam Client, http with internal IP address of the cam). 
What I've just seen on the Firefox Dev Tool are a line of fcgi command, my username and my password.

Are they supposed to be seen on the dev tool, or are they supposed to be hidden over an encryption?

Thanks :-) and happy holiday

Comment: They are supposed to be seen. They are only encrypted (i.e. https) when being sent over the network. I assume you meant 'https' when you wrote 'http'.

Comment: No, I really meant http when I wrote http. Foscam is still using http for calling their IP Cam Client on the browser. And they are still using NPAPI for their IP Cam Client (Web UI for viewing the live video streaming and setting stuffs on the cam).

Comment: That seems crazy, but this is starting to sound like it's not a programming question.